# Multiple entry points for nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, webpack-4

I'm a noob with webpack and was wondering how I can set up multiple entry points using the `nuxt.js` framework.

I was looking at the latest webpack documentation, https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#object-syntax

```
module.exports = {
/*
 ** Headers of the page
 */
head: {
    title: 'nuxt-boilerplate',
    meta: [
        { charset: 'utf-8' },
        { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
        {
            hid: 'description',
            name: 'description',
            content: 'Meming'
        }
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }]
},
/*
 ** Customize the progress bar color
 */
loading: { color: '#3B8070' },
/*
 ** Build configuration
 */
build: {
    // analyze: true,
    /*
     * 
     ** Run ESLint on save
     */
    extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
        if (isDev && isClient) {
            config.module.rules.push({
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                // loader: 'eslint-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/
            })
        }
    }
},
srcDir: 'src/',
rootDir: './'
}
```

Any tips would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What you trying to solve by this?

Comment: I need two separate index files for separate purposes, I'm trying to build out a redirect system and don't want a user to go to the landing page and then get redirected, just directly get redirected

Comment: Still dont understand

Comment: Essentially, I am building an url shortener application, and so it makes sense to have two different entry points, one to make urls and another for redirection.

Comment: essentially I don't want them to see the main screen and then get redirected, just redirected

Comment: @GrandFleet have you had a look at https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware?
You may want to implement & register a global middleware for your redirect purpose? Also have a look at `redirect` method of nuxt context https://nuxtjs.org/api/context

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this is an exclusively client-side nuxt application, thanks for the advice tho. Maybe I don't understand how middleware works?

Comment: so you would need to make an API call to lookup/resolve your shortened hash -> full URL? How do you want your shortened URLs to look like?

Comment: have a look at https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#dynamic-routes as well. You may want  your landing page to be `./pages/index.vue` + you can then have your redirect component (page) in `./pages/_shortened.vue` - and implement your redirect from within the latter where you can retrieve your shortened hash via 'params'..?

Comment: I mean im not really using a hash or a centralized way of shortening urls, its more like a mapping of ids to urls, works because it is decentralized and i already have a working app, just wanted it to be more like an url redirector, main page is never loaded when going to url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185220/discussion-between-hartmut-and-grandfleet).